# HR:After not working in IE11

Tags: css, internet-explorer

My HR:After content is not working in IE11.  It is supposed to look like this

-------MFG-------

instead of that the border just goes straight through the MFG.  Has anyone encountered this problem with IE11?

If you would like to view it you can checkout rangaire.herokuapp.com

css below:

```
hr:after {
    content: "MFG";
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative; 
    top: -0.7em;  
    font-size: 2.2em;
    padding: 0 0.14em 0 .2em;
    background: white;
    color: #1D2148;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    margin-right: .1em;
    font-weight: 100;
}
```

Comment: Please show your CSS and HTML instead of some ASCII art.

Comment: Just remove `top: -0.7em;`. It looks like that centering `"MFG"` is not working in other browsers...

Comment: i tried that but it moves the mfg below the border.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed it to a div, changing the hr tag to a .mfg class, and then changing hr:after to .mfg::after.